# One column logistration form OR two columns?

Tags: forms, usability, login, registration

Don't look at me like that, I actually like the way to call both login and registration forms together a logistration form, well it's convenient.
I've designed a logistration form, but the problem is that I want to know which approach do you think you're more comfortable with, a single column or two column approach?
By the way I've read [this article about Two column vs Single column](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/16361/two-column-vs-single-column-registration-page)
I'd actually like to know your own opinion, which one is better?

Two column approach?
[image]

And one column approach:
[image]

Comment: User Experience isn't a field where opinions of non-users matter.

Comment: @dnbrv Opinions of non-users as in "Expert Evaluation"? :)

Comment: It is hard to get used to looking at non-English (or right to left reading path). Hope you have more questions on UXSE for use to answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[When you have a **single** form, it's best to use a single column](http://baymard.com/blog/avoid-multi-column-forms), because the path to completion is less confusing. However, here you have **two forms** on the same screen, and the user will never switch between the two - either he fills out one, or the other. So that's a very different scenario.

In this case the one column approach is problematic because the bottom form is hidden from view. For instance, if you put the log in at the top, then users might not discover the registration hidden below the fold. They will see the page as a log in form and will try to find the registration page elsewhere. If you do this in two columns, you prevent that problem and you should only make sure you have a clear visual separation between the two forms.

Comment: The main problem for one column is exactly like you said: It's not in the view port when user land in the page!

Comment: I see another problem. Inexperienced users will fill all fields, for login and registration. Wanna bet?

Comment: @FrantisekKossuth And you think this won't happen in a single-column layout?

Comment: It will. It was more about mixing signup and login forms into one. Perfect example is in the video linked to similar question (also mentioned above): http://baymard.com/blog/avoid-multi-column-forms

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to have a single column for this type of approach. It makes validation entry easy and without any complexity. On the other hand multicolumn could be cumbersome and complex in terms of showing any validation stuff etc.

meanwhile , make sure your UI doesnt look monotonous in single coulmn , keep some difference in design b/w login and registration contents so that user finds it attractive.

[avoid multi column article](http://baymard.com/blog/avoid-multi-column-forms)

Comment: You mean the UI in the picture seems dull?

Comment: my personal opinion yes,for me it looks monotonous, if you could segregate each with a diff UI it could look more attractive... :)

Comment: thanks for your suggestion I'll take that into real consideration

Comment: glad, good luck!